# Why is one thumbnail image larger than the rest on product collection page bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

All other products thumbnails are equal in size, but for some reason one specific products thumbnail image is noticeably larger than the other ones. We've adjust the image size on photoshop to mirror the others and it's still bigger. We even lowered the image size about 30% smaller than the other products images and it's still loading up equally big. What can we do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

at custom.css

find

```
.item-feature-product .ProductImage img {
   max-height: 650px;
   width: auto;
}
```

replace with below CSS

```
.item-feature-product .ProductImage img {
  height: 350px;
  width: auto;
}
```